# Prevent new CVS repositories

Tags: cvs

I have a CVS-repository, which should be continued to be used for old projects (commits, etc. should be allowed).

However, I want to disable the creation of new repositories.

First thing I tried, was to set the root-CVS-folder to read-only, but now CVS doesn't work at all, because it needs to create a lock-file in the root-folder (which he can't do anymore, because it's read-only)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a patch called CVS ACL (access control list) extension. You can find it (along with instructions) here: http://cvsacl.sourceforge.net